# Line spacing doesn't work in OHAttributedLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, ohattributedlabel

This is the code:

```
NSString *labelString = @"Username: \n some text";
NSMutableAttributedString *labelAttributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:labelString];
...
self.smartLabel.attributedText = labelAttributedString;
```

The label is:

```
Username: some text
```

Instead of:

```
Username:
some text
```

Edit:
The label has enough space to put the text in 1 line, still I want to insert the breakline (programatically!)

Comment: does your label has multiple lines?

Comment: it doesn't matter how much space you have in a one line. If you need a line break you must enable your label to have multiple lines by setting it's `numberOfLines` property to 0 or a higher value than 1.

Comment: If the text is long, the line is breaked correctly. Didn't have to set numberOfLines to 0.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your label has only one line to display increase your label line to two or more than two as shown in given image.
[image]

****Edite**:Since your label is OHAtrributedLabel so you can do the same by code given below**

```
self.smartLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

`self.smartLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`

Comment: OHAttributedLabel is not a regular UILabel. It is not possible to set this value for an OHAttributedLabel using interface builder.

Comment: yeah thats true i did not noticed it.

Comment: Not good, The label has enough space to put the text in 1 line, still I want to insert the breakline (programatically!)

Answer (score 0):

Add this line

```
self.smartLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

and if needed,

```
self.smartLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
```

Comment: my mistake dude i did not notice OHAttributedLabel.